# Как привести DateTime.Now.Day к DateTime

Tags: c#

```
x.CreatedDate <=  DateTime.Now.Day-7
```

"<=" не может выполнится, потому что DateTime.Now.Day не типа DataTime. Как привести к нему?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону метода `.AddDays` (он вполне может принимать отрицательные значения ;))

Comment: можно еще найти разность дат и оценить результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что тип `DateTime.Now.Day` `int`. Попробуй

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите сравнить именно дни, тогда можно так

```
if(x.CreatedDate.Day <= (DateTime.Now.Day-7))
```

Но лучше воспользоваться методом AddDays() и сравнивать именно даты, но не дни, например:  31.01 и 05.02, 5 меньше 31, а если отнять от 5 - 7, то получится вообще отрицательное число :)